# Display ManagedMeta using xslt

Tags: caml-query, data-form-web-part

I am showing the results of query against a document library within a dataformwebpart.  The managed meta data field is named 'Tags'.  The output to the page of this column looks like 3;#test;#2;tos  (where test and tos were text values of 2 properties).

How using xsl can i show test, tos.

The xsl currently outputs .

I would expect this is the problem when outputting any of the managed metadata properties.  I have tried select="@Tags." as well with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
select = "concat(substring-before(substring-after({@Tags},'#'),';'),substring-after(substring-after(substring-after({@Tags},'#'),'#'),';'))"
```

This is just off the top of my head, but it should be pretty close.  Of course, this would only work if there are always two metadata properties returned by @Tags.